# WebM to Canvas Transparency messed up

Tags: javascript, canvas, transparency, alpha, webm

My initial problem is that I have 3 video files that I need to play out without gaps or overlapping, which with visibility and opacity has these problems.

My new idea was to write everything to canvas, but the transparency seems to mess up.

I have tried both pre-multiplied alpha and straight.

The video tag handles them perfectly.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// set canvas size = video size when known
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
});

video.addEventListener('play', function() {
  var $this = this; //cache
  (function loop() {
    if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
      ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0);
      setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 60); // drawing at 30fps
    }
  })();
}, 0);
```

```html
<div id="theater">
<video width="auto" controls="false" height="auto" autoplay="true" id="video" class="stack">
  <source src="http://njastad.com/telenorligaen/straight.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <label>
    <br />Try to play me :)</label>
  <br />
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I just forgot to clear the canvas between each frame...

Answer (score 0):

In order to clear the canvas one can use:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

and then

```
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
```

NOTE: All parameters for clearRect are required